# Creating a Custom Delete Key in GridLayout

Tags: java, android, string, grid-layout

I have a keypad that I created in a `GridLayout` design and I'm looking for a way to create a delete/backspace key as one of the buttons.

My button code is this:

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           digits += "1 ";
           Display.setText(digits);
       }
   });
   two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           digits += "2 ";
           Display.setText(digits);
       }
   });
   .
   .
   .
   nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           digits += "9 ";
           Display.setText(digits);
       }
   });
```

Where `digits` is a string with an initial whitespace value. What's the best way to create a backspace key in this case? I tried something like this:

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           digits += "\b";
           Display.setText(digits);
       }
   });
```

but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to delete the latest character from string "digits":

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (digits.length() != 0) {
        digits = digits.substring(0, digits.length() - 1);
        Display.setText(digits);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I adjusted it from the `digits.length() - 1` to `digits.length() - 2` so both the number and the whitespace were deleted.